# New role not working in Sitecore 9

Tags: sitecore-client, role-management

I have created a new role and  its of Sitecore Domain.I have given the required access and added a user as member.
But I am not able to login with the user. I have tried assigning Member role Sitecore Client Authoring & Sitecore Client Users roles too, but still not able to login
It does not work both normal and Sitecore Identity sever.
Below is the error while login:
[image]

Comment: You can follow Sitecore official doc on how to create a new user and add roles to them from the below links
1. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/create-a-user.html
2. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/add-a-user-to-a-role.html

Comment: You can also refer to this blog - https://www.logicalfeed.com/posts/112/how-to-create-a-login-for-content-author-in-sitecore